# Updating other values in sql when one value is updated

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'd like to create a trigger that updates other rows with the same value in one column but a different in another.

Here's what I mean:

Original:

```
Column a | Column b  | Column C
---------+-----------+-----------
abc      | Maybe     | 01
abcde    | Maybe     | 02
abcde    | Maybe     | 03
abc      | Maybe     | 04
abc      | Maybe     | 05
```

Upon Changing one to Yes:

```
Column a | Column b  | Column C
---------+-----------+-----------
abc      | Yes       | 01
abcde    | Maybe     | 02
abcde    | Maybe     | 03
abc      | No        | 04
abc      | No        | 05
```

To clarify, it's the same table in the before and after. The idea is that changing one value in one column, will alter others with the same value in a different column. The value in common is "abc". So what I'm trying to do is create a trigger so that when I alter the "Maybe" in column b for any one of the "abc"s, the other rows with the value "abc" in column a will automatically have their value in column b changed to "no." I'm having difficulty with what process of operations I would use for this trigger, or how to link the rows together to be affected at the same time.

Comment: You've stated a goal. Now what's your question?

Comment: How would know which one? Is there a criteria?

Comment: Apologies, when making the question, I forgot to add that each row has an id included.

in the example above, the row labeled "01" in column C is the one that's been changed.

Comment: To clarify, it's the same table in the before and after. The idea is that changing one value in one column, will alter others with the same value in a different column. 

The value in common is "abc". So what I'm trying to do is create a trigger so that when I alter the "Maybe" in column b for any one of the "abc"s, the other rows with the value "abc" in column a will automatically have their value in column b changed to "no."

Answer (score 0):

With an `after update` trigger, you could do something like this:

```
update t
  set column_b = 'No'
from t
  inner join inserted i
    on t.column_a = i.column_a
where t.id <> i.id /* the table probably has an id */
--where t.column_b <> i.column_b /* if not */
```